# serial communication in visual studio using windows.h

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I m new to the visual studio I want to trnsfer and receive some data from LPC2148 kit for thisI want to do the serial communication in Visual studio.

I have used dos.h in turboC
Bios.h is also used for the same purpose but those are for Turbo.C compiler

In visual studio I have found a header files Windows in api are writen but I don't know how to use it please help

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) with libraries for handling Serial Communication. You can start from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/Win32_SDK_SerialComm.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial.aspx).

May I also suggest that it will be easier to use C# for this task. You will be able to build the GUI faster and a serial port control is already provided (no need to fight with the API or find a library).

Comment: Actually I m using opencv library for image subtraction, I need to send that data to the board that why I m using C instead of C#.

Comment: I saw that opencv has a python wrapper. If you know python this will be definitely the way to go. Python has a reliable and cross-platform serial library (PySerial) that is very easy to use.

Comment: Changing to (and possibly having to learn) and entirely different language (and a scripted one at that) just to get a serial driver is not really "*the way to go*" at all!

Answer (score 0):

Serial comms in Win32 is not particularly well catered for, the API is somewhat cumbersome to use but is dealt with fairly comprehensively in [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx).

The .Net 2.0 (and later) Framework includes an excellent and easy to use serial communications class that makes the whole process much simpler, but you'll need to use C++/CLI or C# or some other .NET language to access that.

For very simple serial I/O you can always use stdio and simply open the COM*n* device where *n* is the port number you wish to open.  Stdio provides no means to set baud rate and framing etc., but this can easily be achieved by invoking the `mode` command via a system call.  It is crude and lacks the flexibility of the API level interface, but may be adequate for your needs for a quick-and-dirty solution. For example:

```
system( "MODE COM1: BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1" ) ;
FILE port = fopen( "COM1:", "wb" ) ;
fprintf( port, "hello, world!\n" ) ;
fclose( port ) ;
```

Comment: Do I need to include some kind of headers for the same

Comment: @Saurabh:  You'll will of course need the headers that declare the functions that you use;  that is a given in any event. The example code above will need the standard library headers stdlib.h and stdio.h.  Does that really need saying!?