# Socket program for GPRS communication

Tags: c, sockets, gprs

I need to write a `C` program to read data from a `GPRS` modem using *RS232* or *RS485* protocol.
  Can I use socket concept for this purpose ?
Kindly help me with the program by providing some example or link for the same.
Thanks...

Comment: Have a look at these two threads.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525031/serial-communication-in-visual-studio-using-windows-h
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c

Comment: Specifying the hardware layer _RS-232_ or _RS-485_ is not sufficient for the question to be answered; you need to name the higher protocol layer used by the modem.