# Specify COM port file in java

Tags: java, serial-port

In Unix like operating systems, we can access serial ports through files such as `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something. And according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525031/serial-communication-in-visual-studio-using-windows-h), filenames such as `COM1:` can be used to access the serial ports. What is the java alternative for such file names? I don't want to use `Serial Communication` liberaries.

**Edit**

What I want my code to look like is this.

```
String INPUT_PORT_FILE_NAME = linux?"/dev/ttyUSB0":"<File name of comport>"

File in = new File(INPUT_PORT_FILE_NAME)
```

What I want is the widows alternative to a device file.

**EDIT**
I am on a linux machine, and I want to enable my code to be ported easily!

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799178/where-to-download-java-communications-api) if of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on Linux there is access to serial port for instance through device files `/dev/ttyS0`, `/dev/ttyUSB0` and others. It really depends on hardware/chips used to communicate and even distributions.

If same hardware is used in your program it can be partly achieved. When I worked with Serial Comm libraries and real physical serial ports in Linux I used port numbers in config so number 3 meant n=3, so opens "COM"+(1+n) on windows or "/dev/ttyS"+n on linux. Maybe similar can be used for you to accessing port on /dev/ttyUSB"+n

But there is no grantee that port 2 will be `/dev/ttyS1` and COM2 on the same computer after dual boot.

The way not using Serial Comm libraries is hard way and do not recommend it if you want portability in java. I recommend different port config depending on operating system.

Comment: I've added what I want my code to look like.... I wanted to use `File` read write to access my ports. much like how I can access the device files on Linux.

Comment: It is no simpler way as use {Input,Output}stream and Threads. Serial ports are not regular files with "size of bytes" known. It changes and we should implement hooks to catch when data is ready.

Comment: In short u mean you can't access them as a regular file in windows as you can in java?

Comment: No in short I am affraid.